# How to use <=, >=, < and > on a variable stored in a json - python, discord.py

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I have some code for a discord bot which essentialy checks the goblin hp which is stored in a json and if it's not dead it replays the fight sequence. If it is dead(the json variable is less than 0) it should stop the sequence. But it doesn't. I checked the json and the variable was -9 and the code was still looping. Here is the code:

```
@client.command(name='fight_01')
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def fight_goblin(ctx):
    users = await get_bank_data()
    user = ctx.author
    rng1 = random.randint(1, 3)
    hp = users[str(user.id)]['hp']
    users[str(user.id)]['goblin_hp_json'] = 5
    with open("mainbank.json", 'w') as f:
      json.dump(users, f)
    rng2 = random.randint(1, 3)
    if rng1 == int('2'):
        await ctx.channel.send("You searched all around and couldn't find a goblin, try again next time :(")

    elif hp <= 0:
      await ctx.channel.send("You can't go adventuring with no hp you idiot")
        
            
   


     #Define this as async then remove the set hp to 5.
     #THen call it using the loop that the stackoverflow guy gave
    else:

      while True: #an infinite loop
        goblin_hp = users[str(user.id)]['goblin_hp_json']
        if users[str(user.id)]['hp'] <= 0:
          time.sleep(1.5)
          await ctx.channel.send('You died, better luck next time')
                    #If your command stop here you can use return, else use break to get out of the loop, here I will use break
          break
             
                  
    
        if goblin_hp <= 0:
          content3 = 'You did ' + rng5 + ' damage so you killed the goblin, well done'
          await ctx.channel.send(content3)
          rng6 = random.randint(20, 100)
          users[str(user.id)]['bank'] += rng6
          await asyncio.sleep(0.8) #use await asyncio.sleep(0.8) here rather
          content4 = 'You gained ' + str(rng6) + ' coins for defeating the goblin'
                        
          await ctx.channel.send(content4)
          with open("mainbank.json", 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
                    #Same here, I will use break
          break
        else:
          await goblin_fight_sequence(ctx)
                   #(This is where I want it to return to the first else: statement)
                   #Here you can use continue to repeat your loop, or just delete this part (an you will return to the first if). To match with your current code, I will use continue
                   #continue



async def goblin_fight_sequence(ctx):
  await ctx.channel.send('You encountered a wild goblin!')
        
  await asyncio.sleep(1.5) #use await asyncio.sleep(1.5) here rather
  rng3 = random.randint(1, 10)
  if rng3 == int('3') or int('4') or int('7'):
            
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()
    await ctx.channel.send('The goblin got the first hit and you lost 1hp')      

                
    users[str(user.id)]['hp'] -= int('1')
    dmg = users[str(user.id)]['max_damage'] #You forgot an ] here so I replaced it
    rng4 = random.randint(0, dmg)
    rng5 = str(rng4)
    await asyncio.sleep(1.5) #use await asyncio.sleep(1.5) here rather
    content1 = 'You did ' + rng5 + ' damage'
    users[str(user.id)]['goblin_hp_json'] -= int(rng4)
    with open("mainbank.json", 'w') as f:
      json.dump(users, f)
    users = await get_bank_data()
    await ctx.channel.send(content1)
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, can you add the `goblin_fight_sequence` function in your code please, decause I d'ont see anything that indicates that the `goblin_hp `is modified

Comment: I've added the code @Baptiste

Comment: To be honest, I don't have enough information to make a good answer... You have to put in outputs (with prints), traceback if there is, or other things that can help for a solution...

Comment: There were no errors, the code just never stopped looping which means that it always went to the 'else' statement. This means that the if isnt working I guess

Comment: It is weird since you explicitly set users to 5, it should be an int. However when parsing json you might sometimes get str instead of int. Therefore you might want to cast the variable to int at some point. This can be verified by `print(goblin_hp, type(goblin_hp))`.
Otherwise, I really don't know

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by adding users = await get_bank_data() which essentially opens the JSON as read. I added it right under the while true.  To be honest I'm not entirely sure how this fixed it but it did.